# Multiline Java Stream Collect throws

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two types like these:

```
@Data
public class SomePersonType {

    private String name;

    private int age;
}
```

and

```
@Data
@Builder
public class SomeOtherPersonType {

    private String name;

    private int age;
}
```

I need to convert a map of one type to the other. So, my code looks like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final Map<String, SomePersonType> somePersonTypeMap = new HashMap<>();

        // ...
        // populating the map above with some values
        // ...

        final Map<String, SomeOtherPersonType> someOtherPersonTypeMap = somePersonTypeMap.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        entry -> SomeOtherPersonType.builder()
                                    .name(entry.getValue().getName())
                                    .age(entry.getValue().getAge())
                                    .build()
                ));
    }
}
```

My real code contains many other attributes. So, I don't want to do `entry.getValue()` multiple times. I want to put it in a local variable and then use it. Something like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final Map<String, SomePersonType> somePersonTypeMap = new HashMap<>();

        // ...
        // populating the map above with some values
        // ...

        final Map<String, SomeOtherPersonType> someOtherPersonTypeMap = somePersonTypeMap.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        entry -> {
                            final SomePersonType somePersonType = entry.getValue();
                            SomeOtherPersonType.builder()
                                    .name(somePersonType.getName())
                                    .age(somePersonType.getAge())
                                    .build();
                        }
                ));
    }
}
```

But I get two compiler errors:

`Map.Entry::getKey` -> `Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`.
`entry.getValue()` -> `Cannot resolve method 'getValue()'`

Can someone please point me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you forget `return` before `SomeOtherPersonType.builder()...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the lambda expression is concerned, the final statement should return a value so that the value mapping `Function` returns the mapped value:

```
Map<String, SomeOtherPersonType> someOtherPersonTypeMap = somePersonTypeMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    entry -> {
                        final SomePersonType somePersonType = entry.getValue();
                        return SomeOtherPersonType.builder()
                                .name(somePersonType.getName())
                                .age(somePersonType.getAge())
                                .build();
                    }
            ));
```

However, since you're using a builder, then why not have the builder take care of creating the `SomeOtherPersonType` from a `SomePersonType`:

```
public SomeOtherPersonType fromSomePersonType(SomePersonType) {
     ...
}
```

This way you can do:

```
Map<String, SomeOtherPersonType> someOtherPersonTypeMap = somePersonTypeMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    entry -> SomeOtherPersonType.builder()
                                .fromSomePersonType(entry.getValue())
                                .build()
            ));
```